How do I fix an error when trying to pip install cbpro?
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'cgi'
  File "C:PATH.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cbpro
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cgi'


What package are you trying to install? What command did you run? Is that your complete error message?

just a general remark - this package has <1 month of lifespan on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/cbpro/#history in terms of packages like this it's not uncommon that not all of the dependencies are handled (it's 6 years old, some things were working then, but now with new python releases they would no longer work). You have 2 solutions: (1) trial & error fix all failing dependencies (start with installing cgi) (2) downgrade to new back then python 3.6, then (1) should be more trivial...

Module 'cgi' was removed in Python 3.13. If you need to use a package/module that requires cgi — downgrade your Python. Use Python 3.12 or lower.
The last version https://pypi.org/project/cbpro/1.1.4/ declared compatibility with Python 2.6-2.7 and 3.3-3.5. The project seems to be outdated and abandoned, last release was in 2018. Are you sure you want to use it?

Is there an alternative for 3.13?

@DionH I don't know. Official Coinbase Advanced API Python SDK: https://pypi.org/project/coinbase-advanced-py/ . Search: https://pypi.org/search/?q=Coinbase+Pro+API . At least there are more recently updated packages to try. https://pypi.org/project/coinbasepro/ , https://pypi.org/project/myb-coinbase-pro-api/
